# Permission request form is broken, approve button is hidden, css variables are missing

Tags: bug, status-completed, oauth2

You can check that form doesn't work with this link `https://stackoverflow.com/oauth?client_id=17581&scope=no_expiry&redirect_uri=http://functional.localdomain:3449/login/github`

[image]

Comment: Probably related to the [Dark Mode](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/395949/4751173)

Comment: Is there a way to force the website to use the standard mode when loading the page?

Answer (score 1):

This was reported on [MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/396419) and is now fixed. Adam Lear said:

> Looks like I was right and we were, in fact, missing the design library reference.
>
> The fix is live in production. Thanks for the report!