# OAuth implicit login dialog layout on Mobile Safari needs improvement

Tags: feature-request, oauth2

On mobile safari (iOS 13.3.1) the layout of the dialog page could be improved.

On opening the page look like this on an iPhone11:

[image]

The reasoning being this request is that the login dialog in the current state can be confusing for users logging in on mobile clients.

Comment: Yes, reported the same thing couple of hours ago https://stackapps.com/questions/8606/permission-request-form-is-broken-approve-button-is-hidden-css-variables-are-m

Comment: Thanks. I'll update it to ask for a better layout on mobile Safari then